# Jquery Nested Data Table with Sort Feature

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I am trying to create Data table inside data table usign jquery. I have achieved creating it with html so far but I want Column sort which isnt possible with my code. Can any one please Guide me how Can I have Data Table inside Data table with Sorting Feature. I have attached Screen Shot for possible Out Come. Where the table in last column should be with Sorting.

I am providing link with Jsfiddle. Some sort of direction would be good. In current implementation I have create nested table with below code which dont give me sorting from Jquery Data table.

```
function createDataTable() {
    var tableHeader = '<thead class="thead-light"><tr><th>Age</th><th>Location</th><th>nationality</th></tr></thead>';
    var tableRows = '';
        var tableRow = '';
        var firstTd = '<td>32</td>';
        var secondTd = '<td>USA</td>';
        var thirdTd = '<td>American</td>';
  
  
        tableRow = '<tr id="1" name="1">'+tableRow+firstTd+secondTd+thirdTd+fourthTd+'</tr>';
        tableRows = tableRows+tableRow; 
  
  
        var tableRow = '';
        var firstTd = '<td>33</td>';
        var secondTd = '<td>UK</td>';
        var thirdTd = '<td>British</td>';
        tableRow = '<tr id="2" name="2">'+tableRow+firstTd+secondTd+thirdTd+fourthTd+'</tr>';
        tableRows = tableRows+tableRow;   
        return '<table class="table table-bordered" id="1" name="1">'+tableHeader+'<tbody>'+tableRows+'</tbody>'+'</table>';
}
```

This Returned Table is then assigned to last Col of data table with something like .

```
dtRow[8] = createDataTable();
```

IT gives something like this in Image. [image]

Please Guide me how can i achieve Sorting on Nested Data table for last row.

JS Fiddle :

[JS Fiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/jordan_josh3184/nrb5h2d3/66/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a full DataTable inside each cell of the `Examiner` column, and then initialize all those nested DataTable instances to sort in whatever order you need.

You have not shown us how you source your data, so I will give a demo which uses my own test data as JavaScript-sourced data. But the techniques are the same, regardless of how the data is sourced (JavaScript, Ajax, etc.):

1. Build a string containing the full `<table>` HTML for each nested table.
2. Give each of these tables a class name. I will use `class="childTable"` in my demo.
3. After the main parent table has been initialized, then use the child table class name to mass-initialize every child table.

Here is a demo:

```js
var dataSet = [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "details": [
        {
          "language": "Java",
          "level": "1 - advanced"
        },
        {
          "language": "C++",
          "level": "2 - intermediate"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Cedric Kelly",
      "position": "Javascript Developer",
      "details": [
        {
          "language": "JavaScript",
          "level": "1 - advanced"
        },
        {
          "language": "Python",
          "level": "3 - beginner"
        }
      ]      
    }
  ];
 
function formatChildTable ( data ) {

  var table_string =  '<table class="childTable display dataTable cell-border"><thead>' +
    '<tr>' +
      '<th>Language</th>' +
      '<th>Level</th>' +
    '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    
  
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    var row_string = '';
    row_string = row_string + 
      '<tr>' + 
        '<td>' + row.language + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + row.level + '</td>' +
      '</tr>';
    table_string = table_string + row_string;
  });

  table_string = table_string + '</tbody>' + '</table>';

  return table_string;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  data: dataSet,
  columns: [
    { 
      data: "name" 
    },
    { 
     data: "position" 
    },
    { 
      data: "details",
      render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        return formatChildTable( data );
      }
    }
  ],
  initComplete: function(settings, json) {
    // mass-initialize every child table using the `childTable` class as the selector:
    $('.childTable').DataTable({
      dom: 't',
      order: [[1, 'desc']] // sort on the last row, descending order
    });
  }

} ); 




} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Details</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The end result looks like this:

[image]

In my case I chose to sort the child tables using `order: [[1, 'desc']]`.

I also used `dom: 't'` to hide all the other [standard controls](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) you get by default, so only the table itself is displayed.

Comment: I am getting sort option on Details.

Comment: could you please Guide me based on new code what I am doing wrong.. Once we intialized it in inticomplete it should give us all option but its giving sort option on Details instead of table columns.

Comment: I don't fully understand that code you posted in an answer (which should not be in an answer, by the way). Why are you using `$.ajax({...})` to fetch your data? Why not use DataTables to [handle the Ajax call](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html)? There should be no need for any of that code you have which builds the table manually, row by row (`table.row.add(dtRow);`). Maybe you can significantly simplify your code, by doing this - and then maybe the sorting problem will be clearer (or maybe you will actually fix it yourself).

Comment: sure.let me try to do that.

Comment: It may also help if you show us a representative sample of the raw JSON data you get via Ajax. You can add that to the question also (as formatted text, not a screenshot). If we can see the overall structure of that JSON data, and some sample rows, then that might make troubleshooting a lot easier. Stack Overflow is not really set up for iterative debugging - but a [mre] can help.

Comment: will take time and create new JSfillde with more bet representation..thank you

Comment: Hi AndrewJAmes , I am able to implement it .. https://jsfiddle.net/jordan_josh3184/nrb5h2d3/122/ . thank you